# When drawing on a canvas, does layout care about 1 pixel differences in size?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, canvas

if I have an object that measures into a region that is size 100, and then i draw a line from 0-100 using a brush with a pixel width of 2, the content will go outside the measured region.

will the fact that the content is larger than the measured size force a layout update? I'm just wondering how picky the layout system is.

Comment: with `Canvas`, No a layout pass will not be run if applying larger content, `Canvas` is a simple layout parent that uses the child X,Y,Width and Height to layout controls/shapes, however depending on the `ClipToBounds` property on the `Canvas` the larger contenet may still be rendered on screen

Answer (score 1):

Anything you draw to the canvas element will be clipped to the maximum size of the canvas element and/or by a path if you use that as as clip.

Nothing you draw to a canvas element through its context will invoke any layout update of other elements in the browser. The context is completely isolated and is basically a bitmap that you manipulate at a different level than the other elements in the browser.

So the answer to this will be no.

However, it's worth to mention that updates in the browser *may* influence the content of the canvas (ie. clears it) so have this in mind, in particular with browser window re-sizes. You can listen to the `resize` event to perform updates of the canvas when necessary.